# Does application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: gets called when a device receives a push notifcation?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I read that if the app is in a terminated state (as long as it's not forced quit by the user) it will be awakened once it receives a push notification. When this happens, does the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: get called even though the user hasn't really interacted with the push notification to go to the app yet?
What if there's a content-available flag in the push notification? Will there be a difference in the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` is only ever run when the app is not open and the user taps the notification (or it is not open and then opened normally). By tapping the notification, the application *launches*. *Launching* is a specific process [that happens before the app becomes alive, so to speak.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app/about_the_app_launch_sequence) As a result, `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` is not called at another other point than launch, like when a notification is displayed.

Comment: What if the user hasn't tapped on the notification yet? The device will wake the app right? Does the application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) gets run right away even if the user hasn't really interacted with it?

Comment: I added my response to the original answer at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much. Even when there's a content-available=1 flag in the push?

Comment: @cessmestreet I am so sorry– I made a mistake in my answer. The answer is when the `content-available` flag is 1 and you use the function in my answer, a display of a notification can trigger the function.

Comment: Okay so, even if content-available=1 flag wakes up my app from the terminated state, it won't trigger the application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) unless the user taps on the notification right?

Comment: I just edited my post to make it _way_ more pointed and specific to the question.